# How to add CCAvenue in Magento 2.1.1

Tags: magento2, payment-gateway

I search Cc Avenue  extension in Magento 2 but not any extension is display CCAvenue  extension. Please suggests the it is available or not available extension in Magento 2 Cc Avenue  extension.

Comment: check with official ccavenue team once....

Comment: Please contact cc avenue providers. They will provide you surely.

Comment: ccavenue magento 2 extension kit https://mars.ccavenue.com/downloads/Integration_kits.zip

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below free extension for CCAvenue Payment Gateway.

https://github.com/Kingsman-The-Secret-Service/Magento2-Ccavenue-Payment-Gateway-Module

Hope it help!

Answer (score 0):

CC Avenue itself offers an official kit (Module) for Magento, one you signup and login to your Merchant down, you can find in your downloads area.